# Use moustache inside moustache brackets in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, insert, mustache

I’m pretty new to Vue.js and love it so far. There’s only one problem I have: How do I render a string AND things inside the string?
For example:

```js
//…
data:{
string:"hi, {{name}}",
name:"John Doe"
}
```

```html
{{string}}<!—won’t work —>
<span v-html="string"></span><!—neither this —>
```

I want to insert “string” into the html and afterwords insert “name”.

The “Hello {{name}}” should inserted after an Ajax call and therefore not be featured in the HTML.

The output should be “hi, John Doe”.

**To make it clear, what I want to have is:**

```html
{{string}}
<!-- becomes-->
hi, {{name}}
<!--finally becomes-->
hi, John Doe
```

Comment: Please add more context on what you do have as input and what you do expect as output. Here it looks like `hi, {{name}}` have nothing to do with vuejs but should be template literal (vanilla es6 js), so using another syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed property to return string with data variable inside string;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{this.stringWithVar}}</h1>
  </div>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
      name: 'John Doe'
      },
      computed: {
        stringWithVar: function () {
          return `hi, ${this.name}`;
        }
       }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, the “Hello {{name}}” should  not be featured in the HTML. Thanks anyways

Comment: for common Vue of course, but not in this context, since I especially wanted the {{name}} to be rendered into another {{string}}

Comment: I see, you may want a computed property to return a string with a variable inside this string. I'll edit my reply.

Comment: I tried to make it clear with another example in the edit

Comment: Edited my reply, using a computed property to return string with data variable inside string.